# AWS Ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am getting this error while connecting(through ssh) to an EC2 instance: **No authentication methods available(server sent public key)** and I am **not able to locate the .PEM file stored in ubuntu Ec2 instance?** Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for the above question..We have to transfer the downloaded .PEM file from **local filesystem (i.e Windows)** to **Amazon Ec2 instance (i.e Ubuntu)** **using SCP or Filezilla**. Check the below link

**http://angus.readthedocs.org/en/2014/amazon/transfer-files-between-instance.html**

After moving .PEM file to specific location (**For Ex: home/ubuntu/.ssh or ~/.ssh**) in ubuntu.. use following command to SSH

**ssh -i /path/to/.PEM username@DNS-name-of-instance**

OR

**ssh -i /path/to/.PEM username@private-ip-of-instance**

Answer (score 0):

EC2 machine doesn't contains the .PEM file.User have to download it at the time of creating EC2 instance, it's a onetime downloadable file.Using this file user can communicate with EC2 machine.For windows user, convert .pem file to .ppk file using putty keygen.for linux user, they can use directly.